# Programmatically add Fragment to inner ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I'm attempting to add a two Fragments to the following layout:

**dialog_empty_linear_layout.xml:**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ParentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Using the following code:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_empty_linear_layout);

int parentViewId = getIntent().getIntExtra(PARENT_VIEW_ID, -1); // == R.id.ParentLayout
if (parentViewId == -1)
    parentViewId = android.R.id.content;

/*
 * Extracting Fragments types
 */
Class<? extends Fragment>[] fragmentTypes = getFragments(); // there are two fragments here!

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
for (Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentType  : fragmentTypes) {
    Fragment fragment = Tools.createNewInstance(fragmentType);
    ft.add(parentViewId, fragment);
}
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

While executing the code I receive the following error:

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.*

I was quite surprised because this is a **newly created Activity, with a newly created fragments and newly created views**...

So I've followed the stack trace and checked which child and which parent are we talking about since the exception did not gave any extra info about it...

I was more surprised to find out the Child is the LinearLayout(e.g. R.ParentLayout), and the Parent was the RelativeLayout wrapping it.

Perhaps once again I miss the obvious but I thought that:

```
ft.add(parentViewId, fragment);
```

Suppose to add the Fragment to the parentViewId layout, and not to attempt to add the parentViewId layout to its parent layout...

**ALSO, if I use the following XML everything works fine:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ParentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**Any insights?**

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but if you create your fragments by using an inflater (`getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root))` and you don't set the second parameter to `null` then the fragment will be attached to that ViewGroup as its parent so when you reference it in your code it'll already be attached to something else.

Comment: And how would the Fragment be attached to the Activity, with out creating a new Layout for the Fragment and attaching it to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, That was interesting... and for those of you that encounter this... pay good attention this is extremely stupid!

Overriding this method in the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container);
}
```

And here is the stupid thing...

The inflater.inflate has another overloading:

```
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container, **addToRoot**);
```

For some reason I expected the fragment layout to be **added to the container**(Don't trust intuition), and not to add the container to the rootView. Until today, I've been adding all my Fragments to my root view, (container == rootView) so this problem didn't occur, but once the container is not the rootView, I **MUST** explicitly state addToRoot=false, e.g.

```
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container, false);
```

Well, that is that guys... stupidity by a boolean!